# How can I query localhost server from my website with javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, networking, browser, localhost

I have a website running on, for example, `mydomain.com`. Then i am starting local backend server at `localhost:3000` (`127.0.0.1:3000`). Can I add some js code to this website so it will query my local backend? Since my browser and my local backend are on same computer I guess it can access my local backend somehow. I tried creating a codepen
https://codepen.io/dranitski/pen/ExNZLJo?editors=1111
with this code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/').then(r=> r.json().then(j=> console.log('\nREQUEST',j)));
```

And created `test.js` file locally with content:

```
require('http').createServer(function (req, res) { res.end('' + process.pid); }).listen(3000);
```

then started it with `node test.js`

But my codepen gives me an error
`Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/'`

I can claim backend is working since i can access `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` from my browser and see the result successfully.

*The idea behind that is to create a website that can interact with backend running locally on user's machine. My users have our backend server started locally and I need an online tool that can query these as well showing them some data from their local backends in human-readable form.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of query would you like to run? Query an SQL database? A text file? A file system? Also, I believe Node.js is what you're looking for. Node.js is a backend language built on JavaScript (the V8 engine as far as I'm aware). What you could do is make an XMLHTTP request to a Node.js server, have that Node.js server query the database/file/file system using the user input (make sure it's clean first), and then have the Node.js server return the results. This can all be done with Node.js' built-in http module.

Comment: Note that you could also do this with PHP (in a more simple way), but you specifically requested JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried using AJAX? If you really can visit http://127.0.0.1:3000 in your browser and this isn't working in your JavaScript then I expect it's a problem with the XMLHttp confit. Try using a simple Ajax get request and console.log both the response and also the error in the error callback if any: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: If you need to access your server from the *outside*, you need to query your [external ip address](https://checkip.amazonaws.com). 127.0.0.1 would be pointing to the localhost you run your script on (codepen server in your case).

Comment: Yes have just noticed you are using codepen. Why? Codepen runs on codepen, it can't access your localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works!

Just needed to enable cors on local node server

`test.js`

```
require('http').createServer(function(req,res){
    // Set CORS headers
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    res.end('' + process.pid);

}).listen(3000);
```

then run it with `node test.js`

Now the pen can access the server!